# The exception message is 'Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, database, wcf

I try to deploy a simple wcf service which is connected with the mysql5.7 database on sever it through an error, but the same application when i run into my local machine it works fine (my local machine also have a mysql5.7 database) i don't have any idea why this error comes .

i all ready added Mysql.Data.dll 6.9.9.0;

error is:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is

> 'Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'. See server
>   logs for more details

. The exception stack trace is:

> at MyServiceBecouseError.MyNameService.nameInput(String input, String
>   inputwo) at SyncInvokenameInput(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="MyServiceBecouseError.MyNameService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web" contract="MyServiceBecouseError.IMyNameService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />  
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
<runtime>
  <dependentAssembly>                                   
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

simple method under the application which connect database and insert data into database;

```
 public class MyNameService : IMyNameService
    {


        public string nameInput(string input, string inputwo)
        {
            string myDataString = "Server=localhost;Database=foo;Uid=root;Pwd=qwerty;";

            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(myDataString);
            MySqlCommand cmd;
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText= "INSERT INTO foo.footable (id,name,lastName) VALUES (@id,@name,@lastName)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", int.Parse(3.ToString()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", input);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", inputwo);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            return "hello pushpam";
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the .net framework version tally with the IIS application pool?